# ASP.NET MVC Render Form With Route Values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

The route for my view is like this:

```
http://localhost/project1/join/register/ABCDEFGH/12345678
```

The last two parts are the parameters which I accept as part of my route. What I want to do now is to render a form onto the view which has a post method which retains that url.

I am using the BeginForm HTML helper as follows:

```
using (Html.BeginForm(
    "Register", 
    "Join", 
    new { ApplicationKey = Model.ApplicationKey, UserId= Model.UserId}, 
    FormMethod.Post, 
    new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form" }))
```

This renders the forms action tag with a URL as follows...

```
http://localhost/project1/join/register?ApplicationKey=ABCDEFGH&UserId=12345678
```

Is there any way to use the form helper and to retain the format of my route? I can make this work with query string parameters but there are other considerations which mean it would be better if I could get the helper to format the route as it was originally used to access the page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it isn't formatted nicely is because it hasn't found a matching route that fits all the parameters being passed.

You could try Html.BeginRouteForm and use a named route to do it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginrouteform(v=vs.118).aspx